# Excel charts with #N/A values

Tags: c#, excel

I have written a C# program that does a lot of iterative calculations and then returns a huge list of data. Because the data changes each time I run the program, I draw it in an Excel spreadsheet with predefined functions and graphs that are useful to interpret the data. However, all my charts in the spreadsheet depend on a single column of data, through with other columns and axis are calculated using formulas. However, the total amount of data is not always constant.

For instance, sometimes I get 22 elements of data in the list, and sometimes the number flows into 100s. To have a stable bound, I cap the charts to graph only the first 50 rows of data, and in my program, I fill the remaining columns with the value "#N/A". However, when I open the spreadsheet, the rows with superfluous data is graphed as `0`s. I want the charts to graph only the rows with valid data.

Here is what my code looks like, it is relatively very simple, so I am not going to modify this, I want to know what changes I can make in the spreadsheet.

```
            FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo("Report.xlsx");
        ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage(newFile);
        ExcelWorksheet ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets[1];        

        int cellCount = 2;
        for(int i = 0; i < 49; i++)
        {
            String cell = "B" + cellCount;
            if (i < data.Count)
                ws.Cells[cell].Value = data.ElementAt(i);
            else
                ws.Cells[cell].Value = "#N/A";

            cellCount++;

        }

      Console.Out.WriteLine("saving");
        pack.Save();
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Report.xlsx");
```

To access the Excel documents, I use EPPLUS. Here is what my charts look like:

[image: how my charts look]

As the graph shows, the last 5-6 rows contain NULL values, however, they are graphed as well, with values of `0`. The blue line represents the data in the third column, and red line represents the last column (that is never going to be null because it's dependant on a fixed row).

How do I force Excel to ignore the last few NULL rows?